# Can't figure out why I keep getting undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner so I apologize for the "easy" question. Thank you.

```js
let majority = (arr, call) => {

  let reducedArr = arr.reduce(function(accu, item, index) {
    if (call(item) >= index) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  })
}

const isOdd = function(num) {
  return num % 2 === 1;
};

console.log(majority([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], isOdd)); // should log: true
console.log(majority([2, 3, 4, 5], isOdd)); // should log: false
```

Comment: Your braces aren't balanced. Please post code that runs.

Comment: Wasn't aware! thank you

Comment: @Dom You don't have to return `accu` -- whatever you return will become `accu` in the next call, and the last returned value is the final result.

Comment: `majority()` doesn't have a `return` statement. It needs `return reducedArr;`

Comment: But your use of `reduce` is wrong. `isOdd()` returns `true` or `false`, why are you comparing that to the array index?

Comment: In general, if the function called by `reduce` doesn't use `accu`, something is wrong. The whole point of `reduce` is to combine the results from each call into the accumulator.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I was just testing things as I try to figure out the challenge.

Comment: What are you intend to do here?

Comment: If the number of true returns is equal to the number of false returns, majority should return false.

Answer (score 4):

`majority()` needs to return something. Since it doesn't have a `return` statement, it returns `undefined` by default.

Your `reduce()` logic is all wrong, since it's not using the accumulator parameter.

From the name and your expected results, I assume that the function is supposed to return whether the `call` function is true for the majority of elements in the array. So you can use `reduce` to count the number of true results, by adding `1` to `accu` whenever it's true. Then you `return accu` to update the accumulator as it's iterating through the array.

You also need to supply the initial value of the accumulator as the second argument to `reduce()`. Otherwise, it uses the first element of the arr as the initial value.

Then you need additional code to check if this is the majority. Compare this total to half the length of the array.

```js
let majority = (arr, call) => {

  let reducedArr = arr.reduce(function(accu, item, index) {
    if (call(item)) {
      accu++;
    }
    return accu;
  }, 0);
  return reducedArr > arr.length/2;
}

const isOdd = function(num) {
  return num % 2 === 1;
};

console.log(majority([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], isOdd)); // should log: true
console.log(majority([2, 3, 4, 5], isOdd)); // should log: false
```

Comment: When you return accu, why is it returning 3, 2 ?

Comment: It's returning the number of elements where `isOdd()` is true so far.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return `return reducedArr;` for that piece of code to work how ever i don't think that your logic is correct since you are resetting your accumulator for each element in the array. if you can edit and add what you are trying to accomplish may be we can help you more.

after seeing what you are trying to accomplish here is a snippet with  some comments that my help you understand it better i know reduce can be tricky when you are learning it but you will get the hang of it.

```js
let majority = (arr, call) => {

  let reducedArr = arr.reduce(function( acc, item ) {
    // call(item) returns true if number is odd so there is no need to check it against index
    if ( call(item) ) {
      // if number is odd we increase the odd count in the accumulator
      acc.odd +=1
    } else {
      // if number is even we increase the even count in the accumulator
      acc.even+=1
    }
    return acc;
  }, {odd: 0, even: 0}) //initial accumulator value
  return reducedArr.odd > reducedArr.even; // return true if odd count  is larger than even count
}

const isOdd = function(num) {
  return num % 2 === 1;
};

console.log(majority([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], isOdd)); // should log: true
console.log(majority([2, 3, 4, 5], isOdd)); // should log: false
```

hope this help.